# Prove $\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I need to prove or disprove whether $\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))$ is a tautology. I've determined that this is indeed a tautology, because if $P(x)$ is false for every $x$ then the formula is true, and if $\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ is true and there is at least one $x$ for which $P(x)$ is true and $Q(x)$ is true then both $\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))$ and $(\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))$ are true.

My problem is formulating the formal proof. I have the 3 tautology axioms from Hilbert system

1. $[\varphi\rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \varphi)]$
2. $([\varphi\rightarrow (\psi \rightarrow \theta)]\rightarrow [(\varphi\rightarrow \psi)\rightarrow (\varphi\rightarrow \theta)])$
3. $[(\neg \varphi \rightarrow\neg\psi )\rightarrow (\psi\rightarrow\varphi )]$

and the inference rules are $\frac{\varphi , (\varphi\rightarrow\psi)}{\psi}$ and $\frac{\varphi}{\forall_x\varphi}$. As the second rule doesn't seem relevent here I tried to prove some $\varphi$ and $\varphi\rightarrow \forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))$ then use modus ponens to prove what's needed but I can't get to anything remotely close to that so I tried to prove that $\{\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\}\vdash (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))$ and then by deduction $\vdash \forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))\Longrightarrow \models \forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))$ but here too I'm never able to get only the needed formulae for proving that it is a tautology

---

EDIT: I can get rid of $\exists$ as I don't have an inference rule for this quantifier
$\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\exists_x P(x)\rightarrow \exists_x Q(x))\equiv\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\neg\forall_x \neg P(x)\rightarrow \neg\forall_x \neg Q(x))$

Comment: What rules do you have for $\exists$?

Comment: I don't. I have $\forall_x\varphi\rightarrow \varphi[t/x]$ and $\forall_x(\varphi\rightarrow\psi )\rightarrow (\varphi\rightarrow\forall_x\psi )$ but I was told they are more technical tools rather then used in formal proof

Comment: If you have no rules for $\exists$, then you cannot prove this. (Your semantic argument is correct, but it depends on the meaning of $\exists$, so a syntactic proof must involve some rule about $\exists$: possibly just a definition using $\lnot$ and $\forall$.)

Comment: I can use equivalents to remove $\exists$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Hint*

Without rules and axioms for $\exists$ you have to consider it an abbreviation for $\lnot \forall \lnot$.

Thus, you have to prove $\lnot \exists x Qx \to \lnot \exists x Px$ and then use the third propositional axioms.

This is equivalent to: $\forall x \lnot Qx \to \forall x \lnot Px$ that derives from $\forall x (Px \to Qx)$ by Instantiation and Contraposition and Generaliztion using $\forall x (\alpha \to \beta) \to (\forall x \alpha \to \forall x \beta)$.

Comment: So I managed to prove $\vdash \forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))\rightarrow (\forall_xP(x)\rightarrow\forall_xQ(x))$ and then I get ${\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x))}\vdash (\forall_xP(x)\rightarrow\forall_xQ(x))$ which is equivalent to $(\neg\forall_xQ(x)\rightarrow\neg\forall_xP(x))$ but I don't understand how can I get $\neg$ into the quantifier

Comment: @CforLinux - $∀x(P(x)→Q(x)) \vdash ∀x(¬Q(x)→¬P(x)) \vdash  (∀x¬Q(x)→∀x¬P(x)) \vdash (¬∀x¬P(x)→¬∀x¬Q(x))$

Comment: is the last one really necessary?  $\forall_x(P(x)\rightarrow Q(x)) \vdash (\forall_x\neg Q(x) \rightarrow\forall_x\neg P(x))\equiv (\neg\exists_xQ(x)\rightarrow\neg\exists_xP(X))$ is already proven

Comment: @CforLinux - fine.